# How can I say in Linq: "Where (e => e.tag == tags.AnyValue());"?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
GameObject[] gos = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().Where(g => g.tag == "Bartle" || g.tag == "Doo").ToArray();
```

Now this works fine - I would get only the `GameObjects` that has the tags requested - But the tags will be in an array filled by the user:

```
string[] tags = new[] { "Bartle", "Doo", "etc"};
```

How can I now say:

```
GameObject[] gos = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().Where(g => g.tag == AnyOfTheTagsInTheTagsArray).ToArray();
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Contains` method:

```
(...).Where(g => tags.Contains(g.tag)).(...)
```

Comment: Even better if the tags are in a `HashSet<string>`

Comment: why is it that `HashSet<string>` is faster?

Comment: Because Contains method on HashSet is O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
.Where(g => tags.Any(x=>x==g.tag));
```

`Any` returns true here if any of tags is equal to `g.tag`. Advantage of `Any` is that you can put there any predicate you want.

Comment: Thank you and @MarcinJuarszek Both of your answers are correct - But I think I'm gonna go with yours - Since it's a bit faster than `Contains` (did a simple benchmark)

Comment: I'm surprised that it's faster. It would definitely be slower, is you used `HashSet<string> tags = new HashSet<string>() { "Bartle", "Doo", "etc"};`.

Comment: Tried it - the same. Could it be I'm doing the tests the wrong way?
Just using a `StopWatch` - Starting it before the method call, and stopping it after then checking the `ElapsedMilliSeconds`

Comment: Do you use Release build, without VS attached? I'm working on my perf test, we'll see if it gives the same results.

Comment: @vexe My test results: array+any: 966ms, array+contains: 577ms, hashset+any: 1370ms, hashset+contains: 3ms. `Contains` is faster then `Any`, and look at the `HashSet<string>` and `Contains` method combo - that's incredible difference, isn't it?

Comment: OK that's totally different - could you post the code you used to benchmark and test?

Comment: Hmm, seems like calling `Stop` doesn't reset the timer - You are right, `Contains` is faster. During my test I wasn't calling `Reset` so the times are getting accumulated.